# add_foreign_key vs add_reference in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreign-keys

What is the difference between **"add_foreign_key"** and **"add_reference"** methods in rails?

According to rails official guide all I understand is that they both are used to create foreign key constraint between two tables.

Answer (score 27):

`add_foreign_key` - adds a new foreign key. `from_table` is the table with the key column, `to_table` contains the referenced primary key.

`add_reference` - is meant as a shortcut for creating a column, index and foreign key at the same time.

What is `foreign key` -  a foreign key is a field or group of fields in a table that uniquely identifies a row in another table.

Comment: More than that, a foreign key is a way to maintain referential integrity.  If you have a User that depends on a Location, you would want to prevent the deletion of that Location as long as Users depend on it.  A foreign key is the way to do that.

Comment: Looks like (in Rails 7 at least) that the `foreign_key` option to `add_reference` defaults to false, pass true to add. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference

Answer (score 19):

(**Note**: This answer is based on Rails 6.0.)

In a word, `add_reference` ([Ref](https://api.rubyonrails.org/?q=add_reference#method-i-add_reference)) is kind of a short-form of a combined set of `add_column`, `add_index`, and `add_foreign_key` ([Ref](https://api.rubyonrails.org/?q=add_foreign_key#method-i-add_foreign_key)) **without** adding a DB-level foreign key **in default**. So, when you want to achieve something simple enough or (conversely?) a polymorphic reference, `add_reference` is handy. If not, use `add_foreign_key`, maybe combined with explicit `add_index`.

As a simple example, these two are (I think) equivalent to each other:

```
add_reference   :articles, :author, foreign_key: true

add_column      :articles, :author_id, :bigint, null: true
add_foreign_key :articles, :authors
add_index       :articles, :author_id
```

Here are more detailed differences:

1. The second argument of `add_reference` is a reference (column name without `_id`, hence usually singular), whereas that of `add_foreign_key` is a table name (hence usually plural).
2. In `add_reference`,

   1. DB-level foreign key is **not** created in default, unless `foreign_key` option is specified non-nil.
   2. `index: true` is default, whereas the index is irrelevant in `add_foreign_key`
   3. `null: true` is default (allowing nulls for the column), which is irrelevant in `add_foreign_key`
3. `polymorphic: true` is available only with `add_reference` in Rails (which will create 2 columns in one action; [see Ref](https://api.rubyonrails.org/?q=add_reference#method-i-add_reference)).
4. The formats of the accepted options between the two are totally different, though `add_reference` is largely more inclusive, accepting a wider range of options.

#### Two example realistic use-cases

For the `has_one` association, where null is forbidden:

```
add_reference :products, :merchant, null: false, index: {unique: true}, foreign_key: {on_delete: :cascade}
```

When a table has 2 foreign-key columns to an identical table:

```
add_foreign_key :products, :merchants, column: :seller_id
add_foreign_key :products, :merchants, column: :buyer_id
add_index :products, [:seller_id, :buyer_id], unique: true, name: 'index_my_name_shorter_than_64chars'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I've spent so long searching for an answer that touches on all these things.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limitation to add_reference compared to add_foreign_key.

As I am curious if there is a way to do the exact following thing with add_reference. Afaik the standard *foreign_key to primary_key/reference_key* mapping can not be diverged with add_reference.

Migration snippet

```
add_foreign_key :foos, :bars, column: :foo_key, primary_key: :foo_key, type: :string 
add_index :foos
```

Usecase is when trying to map the foreign_key to the primary_key in a non Standard way. Let's say using a table with [STI](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html) to hold multiple references