# No relationship between tables shown in schema diagram when using add_reference in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, rails-migrations, schemacrawler

I am working on a Rails application where I need to add some of the Foreign keys for existing columns from Rails migrations and few people working on same as well.
 I am adding this way:

```
class AddUserRefToEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_foreign_key :events, :users, name: :index_events_on_user_id
  end
end
```

and one of my mate is adding this way:

```
class AddUserToParts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    add_reference :parts, :user
  end

  def down
    remove_reference :parts, :user
  end
end
```

When we use SchemaCrawler for building schema diagram, the relation is built in between user and events (with `add_foreign_key`) but there is no relation between users and parts (when `added add_reference`).

Can you tell me why? Can we use both (with reference to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52915025/add-foreign-key-vs-add-reference-in-rails)) or only `add_foreign_key`? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact is that `add_reference` **does not** add a foreign key by default. The API Docs for [v5.2](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference) or [v5.0](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference) state that the options hash can include a `:foreign_key` key to set the appropriate foreign key constraint.

So, to use `add_reference`  just change your code to include `foreign_key: true` as an option.

```
add_reference :parts, :user, foreign_key: true
```